# How to use Firebase Cloud Firestore with Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

I want to use the Firestore database to save some input data from Google Chrome Extension (i.e., the user email). I am also using Firebase Authentication which works as expected (i.e., the user is able to login successfully). I am now trying to save the email of the user in the database. However, the code below is not working.

Here is the code (please note that I am not actually saving the email of the user and this is just testing whether the email is being saved in the database):

```
var firebaseConfig = {
...
databaseURL: "project.firebaseio.com",
...
}
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var db = firebase.database();
db.collection("users").doc("test").set({ 
email: "some-email@email.com" 
});
```

Also in the .html page, I have

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com...-firestore.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to save the user's information from firebase authenticated users?

Comment: @JMGelilio Yes, however, I want to save the input that the user inputs in the textarea (in the Google Chrome Extension) to the Cloud Firestore. With this way (above code), I was just testing whether the email is being saved in the "users" collection.

Comment: Sorry but your question still vague, what Google Chrome Extension that you are using? Do you have any documentation that you are following? Did you receive an error? If you have please include it in your question.

Comment: are you integrating the Firebase Firestore to your own Google Chrome Extension? Retrieving the user's data from Firebase Authentication and display to your input textbox/textarea then save to Firestore database?

Comment: throw a look at this: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/chromextension

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to inject Firebase Web Javascript Module version 9+ inside an webpage, here is a gist with an example:

https://gist.github.com/cheadrian/d3a6604c0f680980cd232a89a1719153

Basically you need to refer a Javascript inside "content_scripts" in manifest.json witch will add the Firebase code before close of the <body> tag.